# Morphism of inverse systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

[image]

All maps in the lemma hypothesis are continuous.

This is a lemma from Ribes's Profinite Groups. In this proof there is a claim that I can't see why is true. Lets suppose that all topological spaces are groups. So, we are in the context of topological groups and all the maps are continuous homomorphisms.

Why is $\tilde{X}_i$ a group? I don't know if I'm doing some stupid mistake, but I cannot what ensure, for example, that $\tilde{X}_i$ has identity.

I know if I suppose $\tilde{X}_i$ only a topological space, I will get the result for groups, but I'm looking only to the context of groups so I would like to know a proof involving the group properties.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: [Here's an explanation why you should not rely on pictures to provide key information that is available in another format in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The claim you asked seems to be false. If $\theta_i: X_i \to X_i'$ is a group homomorphism, then $\theta_i(e_{X_i}) = e_{X_i'}$.